# Excel formula to convert numbers from multiple cells, and then add up conversions in one cell

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to figure out a concise way to do this that doesn't require the use of additional columns for variables.

Basically, I have 9 columns, each with a value between 1 and 6. In a special "Meta Score" column, I want run a conversion on the other nine columns. I want look at each value in the other 9 columns, and I want to convert each 1 to a 6, each 2 to a 5, each 3 to a 4, each 4 to a 3, each 5 to a 2 and each 6 to a 1. I then want to add up all these converted numbers and put the sum in the "Meta Score" column.

This can obviously be done in an unwieldy way by creating a corresponding column for each of the 9 columns that stores the conversion and then summing them up. However, is there a simple way to do this that wouldn't require additional columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your original score is in in row in columns A to I, use this formula:

```
=63-SUM(A1:I1)
```

In case any of the cells might be blank and you want to ignore it, use this formula (thanks Barry!):

```
=COUNT(A1:I1)*7-SUM(A1:I1)
```

Comment: Good answer Peter! You might want to cater for empty cells (I assume they would score zero) in which case formula could be adjusted to `=COUNT(A1:I1)*7-SUM(A1:I1)`